# avoid copys when pushing an element into std::queue

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move

I am new to c++11 and would like to have a [std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) storing instances of class `X` and try to avoid unnecessary copies in [push](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/push/) operation.  In c++11, I found `push()` has a rvalue reference version:

```
void push (value_type&& val);
```

So does the following implementation avoids unnecessary copy of `X`

```
std::queue<X> my_queue;

for (...) { // some for loop
  X x;
  ... // some initialization of x
  my_queue.push(std::move(x));
}
```

compared to the following naive implementation?

```
std::queue<X> my_queue;

for (...) { // some for loop
  X x;
  ... // some initialization of x
  my_queue.push(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and only if X supports move semantics the first is is fine.

X might be like:

```
struct X {
    int value;
    X() {
        static int n;
        value = ++n;
    }

    X(X&&) = default;
    X& operator = (X&&) = default;

    X(const X&) = delete;
    X& operator = (const X&) = delete;
};
```

Note: No copy of X is allowed, here.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to answer to such question yourself is to create a probe object.

```
#include <iostream>
struct probe {
    probe() { std::cout << "probe()" << ((void*)this) << std::endl; }
    probe(const probe&) { std::cout << "probe(c&)" << ((void*)this) << std::endl; }
    probe(probe&&) { std::cout << "probe(&&)" << ((void*)this) << std::endl; }
    ~probe() { std::cout << "~probe()" << ((void*)this) << std::endl; }
};
```

and use it instead of X in the test.

I have created a playground [here](http://ideone.com/YxJuQV).

Whether or not the extra copy of anything is performed when you do `std::move` solely depends on what you type in the rvalue reference constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting example code! So the in your output, the destructor has been called twice.  Is it one from `p` and one from the instance pushed into the queue?

Comment: Yep, and depending on whether you use `std::move` or not either `probe(probe const&)` or `probe(probe&&)` is called for the enqueued object